# I can't get tokens in Google Sign-in process

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-signin

I'm trying to write a google drive sign-in for my app.
When I run the code, it gives me the url; Then I open the url and log into it with the email I set before as test user in google cloud console. After that, when I click on exchange authorization code for tokens button, I keep getting this error:

```
{
  "error_description": "Unauthorized", 
  "error": "unauthorized_client"
}
```

This is the code:

```
const {google} = require('googleapis')
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library')

const ClientId = MyClientId
const ClientSecret = MyClientSecret
const RedirectURI = "https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground"
const oauth2client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
    ClientId,
    ClientSecret,
    RedirectURI
);

const scopes = [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"
];

const url = oauth2client.generateAuthUrl({
    access_type:'offline',
    scope:scopes
})

 console.log(url)
```

The weird thing is that when I do this manually, I mean I go to oauthplayground website and I set my client id and client secret manually,it works well and I get the tokens.I'd be really grateful if you could help me with this issue.

Comment: you can't redirect to auth playground